# How to add a + or - to end of an expandable question?

Tags: jquery

I have an FAQ page, and when you click on the question, the answer expands from beneath the question.  I would like to figure out a way to have a "+" at the end of the question, and when you click on it, it changes to a "-".  Is there an easy way to do this?  I'm not sure what code you'd need to give me an answer, so I'll here's the html:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="faq" sort="asc" {gv_param_disable_default}}
    <ul>
    <li class="trigger"><p><a href="#">{faqs_question}</a></p>
        <div class="hidden">
        <p>{faqs_answer}</p>
        </div>

    </li>
    </ul>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

and my jquery:

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
   $(this).children('.hidden').toggle('slow');
return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="faq" sort="asc" {gv_param_disable_default}}
    <ul>
    <li class="trigger"><p><a href="#">{faqs_question}</a></p> <span class="plus">[+]</span><span class="minus">[-]</span>
        <div class="hidden">
        <p>{faqs_answer}</p>
        </div>

    </li>
    </ul>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Javascript

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
   $(this).children('.hidden').toggle('slow', function() {
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
            $(this).parent().children('.plus').hide();
            $(this).parent().children('.minus').show();
        } else {
            $(this).parent().children('.plus').show();
            $(this).parent().children('.minus').hide();
        }
   });
    return false;
 });
```

The parent() should be li.trigger, then we want to select the children .plus & .minus to change visibility.

Additionally, you'll have to hide the [-] on page load (preferably in the css).  If you want the minus/plus to be clickable, just move them into the a tag.

Answer (score 2):

You could use CSS-generated content to do this by toggling the class of li.trigger along the following lines:

(I simplified your HTML a bit):

```
<ul>
  <li class="trigger">
    <p class="question"><a href="#">{faqs_question}</a></p>
    <p class="answer">{faqs_answer}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('open').children('.answer').toggle('slow');
  return false;
});
```

CSS:

```
li.trigger p.answer {
  display: none;    
}
li.trigger p.question:after {
  content: "+";
  padding-left: .5em;   
}
li.open p.question:after {
  content: "-";
}
```

You could style this more; I just added a little padding.